# Send delay after wifi roam

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, wifi

I have a use case that requires a lot of wireless roaming and I'm hitting an issue where there is a delay sending packets after a roam of about 1 second however I can receive packets almost instantly (<100ms).

Looking at the netlink traffic I can see that the supplicant is setting the interface to IF_OPER_UP and it is returning IF_UP as expected. Looking at a tcpdump I can see that there is a gap in send traffic after a roam and that the send traffic resumes after an ARP request/response. I'm not that familiar with linux networking so I'm a bit lost what might be causing this. I think the ARP cache is being cleared but I don't know if that is a cause or a symptom or even what is expected to happen in a roam.

I have tried multiple different kernel versions, both iwd and wpa_supplicant, and ubuntu and kali, all with the same results.

Finally this seems to have just started after upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 which runs the 4.15 kernel.

Does anyone know where I can look next to narrow down what is going on?
Does anyone else see this?

Comment: Check this SF Q/A (and the last linked commit in my answer): https://serverfault.com/questions/1083698/linux-what-causes-static-arp-entries-to-flush-on-link-down/1083762#1083762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close out this question, the issue is in kernel 4.20 a change was introduced that always clears the ARP cache on roam which in turn causes the ~1 second send delay.

In addition to the details in this answer
https://serverfault.com/questions/1083698/linux-what-causes-static-arp-entries-to-flush-on-link-down/1083762#1083762

The iwd supplicant adds a patch here to use this new option which is the other half of the fix:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/commit/?id=873924a027ad2166436b8117a6bb84ce980ad7f3

```
commit 873924a027ad2166436b8117a6bb84ce980ad7f3
Author: James Prestwood <prestwoj@gmail.com>
Date: Wed Nov 3 15:15:01 2021 -0700

    station: set evict_nocarrier sysfs option during roaming

    If the kernel supports evict_nocarrier set this during the roam
    to prevent packet delays post roam.
```